# How to form protobuf resource part of http request body and test it through dhc client or postman for restful services

Tags: java, rest, postman, protocol-buffers, dhclient

I have created a .proto message and I'm exposing a rest service which looks like this

```
@Path("/test")
public interface test{

@POST
@Produces("application/x-protobuf")
@Consumes("application/x-protobuf")
public Response getProperties(TestRequest testrq);
}
```

Now TestRequest being the Java generated file of .protobuf how do i pass it in request body ?

this will be be the .proto file format

```
message TestRequest
{
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    enum TestType
    {
        Test=1
    }
   TestType testType = 3; 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code snippet to test the protobuf as i don't find any solution with postman or dhcclient

```
URL url = new URL("https://localhost:8080/test");
HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlc.setDoInput(true);
urlc.setDoOutput(true);
urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-protobuf");
urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-protobuf");
TestRequestPb.TestRequest.Builder testRequestBuilder = TestRequestPb.TestRequest.newBuilder();
TestRequest testRequest = testRequestBuilder.build();
testRequest.writeTo(urlc.getOutputStream());

testRequest = TestRequest.newBuilder().mergeFrom(urlc.getInputStream()).build();
```

Comment: Postman works fine with binary protobuf request body. Just use `protoc` or your app code to generate the binary request body as a local file, then in your Postman GET to the endpoint, make sure you have `Content-Type application/protobuf` in the headers, and for the Body select `binary` and then select your protobuf binary file.

Answer (score 8):

Give [Protoman](https://github.com/spluxx/protoman) a try if you need a simple protobuf api client.

Disclaimer: It's my side project

Comment: Thank you @spluxx for building this client. It was much needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [protoCURL](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl), a command line tool, to send Protobuf payloads to your HTTP REST endpoints and debug it. It works just like with cURL - except that you can use the [Protobuf text format](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl#protobuf-text-format) or JSON format to describe your request, which will be automatically encoded and decoded. Since the accepted answer does not actually use postman or dhc client, I think that a CLI might be acceptable for you or other readers.

In your case the request would look like this:

```
protocurl -I path/to/proto -i ..TestRequest -o ..TestResponse \
  -u http://localhost:8080/test \
  -d "id: 'myid', name: 'myname', testType: Test"
```

assuming your .proto file is in the folder `path/to/proto`.

However, because your .proto file does not specify the response type TestResponse, it's not possible to display it. You would need to add a response message to your .proto file. There is however an [open issue](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl/issues/10) for displaying responses even without its message schema.

You can find [examples for outputs in the repository.](https://github.com/qaware/protocurl/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md)

Disclaimer: I am the creator of this and made it, because I encountered the same problem.